# Make safari use normal `back` and `forward` button as other browser

Tags: keyboard, safari, mouse, shortcut

As you might know, Safari use different short to go forward and back in history, `CMD+[` and `CMD+]`. How do I change that to use normal back and forward button as on most mouse and other browser?

Comment: Actually Safari *does* use standard back/forward keys. The problem comes up when some pages do something on the page that makes back/forward using COMMAND-[BACK/FORWARD ARROW] fail. A lot of sites even capture the navigation back/forward buttons to keep you on the page. I have no idea what this accomplishes other than to annoy someone but I have found that the COMMAND-[ or ] works more reliably than the "standard" COMMAND-ARROW keys. Perhaps this is what you are referring to?

Comment: They want you to buy an Apple mouse, so there will never be an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

macOS doesn't natively support using mouse buttons for forward and back. You can use gestures if you have an Apple trackpad or a magic mouse, but not buttons.

However, there are a number of apps that will do this. One lightweight option is https://sensible-side-buttons.archagon.net/

P.S. I also have a personal fork of this app with some idiosyncratic features I wanted—e.g. hold down the middle mouse button while pressing a side button to use the side button's native behavior. https://github.com/Wowfunhappy/Side-Button-Enabler/releases

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't know why someone downvote you. MacOS actually very stupid and pain to work with if you're not using Apple walled garden equipment. I do have magic mouse and keyboard but they're nowhere near as good as my 3rd party mechanical keyboard/mouse

Comment: (I have enough rep to see vote totals, and no one has ever downvoted this answer as of September 18, 2020. Anyway, you're welcome!)

Comment: This doesn't work on Apple Silicon. Prefer @PAPPL's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

I used karabiner elements to map button5 to cmd+] and button 4 to cmd+[ (being forward and back) but used the "front_most_application_if" condition for it to be only active in safari so they are still the normal buttons in other apps.

The code I used:https://pastebin.com/LvpZRmee

Comment: Thanks for this!! Finally I can use my non-Apple mouse with Safari. I created your rule in the online Karabiner editor and thought I would share it in case someone else wants to give it a try: https://bit.ly/3QgR72Q (I had to use a URL shortener cause the original URL is way to big).

Comment: Both your solutions don't work for me. Even a simple modification like `"to": [{"key_code": "a"}]` doesn't work, and EventViewer correctly sees button4... macOS 11.6.8, Safari 16.0, Karabiner 14.10.0

Answer (score 5):

**Tried many, only easy and reliable way to enable back/forward is:**

https://github.com/thealpa/SaneSideButtons

It simulates Trackpad 3-finger swipe back/forward, even works on Roccat mouse with back using Button 1+4 together. :-)

Opensource on Github.
Download latest release, open ***SaneSideButtons.dmg*** -> Move to Applications Folder -> Start app and grant permissions -> Enable in MacOS (top bar icon)

[image]

Done, top!

Comment: It's also available as a Homebrew cask: `brew install sanesidebuttons`

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts you can set shortcuts for Safari. Specify "Back" for the menu text and then select the "normal back" button. (What is this button? Do you mean the arrow keys? Mapping back to the back arrow could cause you to jump off of a page when you only intended to move your cursor back while typing some text in a web form.)

Comment: Just FYI, the “normal” Back button is *Backspace*